# Prevent page from reloading after JQuery triggers

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, reload

I'm currently trying to load a web page where complementary data is loaded through ajax when clicking on a "read more" button, but when the script is finished the page reloads. Any tip on how to prevent the page from reloading?

I tried `event.preventDefault` and `return false;` but that doesn't seem to work.

Here's my code:

```
window.setInterval(function () {
        $('div.getmore').trigger('click'); 
        return false;
       }
, 1000);
```

Comment: You need to look at the handlers registered with `getmore` whether they are doing it

Comment: `$('div.getmore').on('click', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); })`

Comment: @marwann it must a javascript error that you are encountering or your form might be getting submitted somehow. Try my anwser and see what error you get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not in your jQuery code that you pasted. Try using firebug console and click persist to make sure you see the javascript error even after page is loaded, you will then be able to find the real issue.

Comment: I'll accept it as the right answer @shivgre as it helped me broaden my perspectives. To give some context, the site is not mine but a blog I like to read, and I find it painful to browse it as it doesn't have a search bar. The problem was the div still exists even when all content is already on the page, but its visibility is hidden and if the hidden button is clicked then it reloads page.

Comment: Glad it helped, hope it helped you fixed the reload issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this , this should work

```
window.setInterval(function (e) {
        $('div.getmore').trigger('click'); 
        e.preventDefault()
        e.stopPropagation()
       }
, 1000);
```

Comment: No, `return false;` does both. Issue is something else.

Comment: `return false;` is equivalent to `e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();` - And it doesn't help using it.

Comment: maybe somthing is happening after clicking $('div.getmore')

Answer (score 0):

You should `preventDefault` click on an `a` element. Not the `div` if it's inside the `a`:

```
<a href="google.com">
    <div class="getmore">Get more</div>
</a>

$('a').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});

// Your code
```